# Sqlite3 not working in windows command line

Tags: windows, sqlite

My sqlite3.exe is working if i run it from the explorer but can't work when i run from a command line. I tried almost everything. It only prints a newline.
My sqlite3 is in the path, so clearly it's coming from there (even if i precise he entire path, it's not working).

I see windows doing a report in background so i looked for an error in the event viewer.
The exception is only 0xc0000005 with unknown failing module.

Windows version : 10 (updated)
Sqlite3 verison : 3.30.1

Comment: Does running it as `sqlite3 -interactive` help?

Comment: Nope sorry, even the -version doesn't work